# How to add custom css to a styled-component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to realise how to render CSS inside a styled component if I'm getting it as a string? `"background: red; color: green; display: flex"` 
Normally I'm using a function renderThemeProperty

```
export declare const renderThemeProperty: (themePropName: string, styleName: string, force?: boolean | undefined) => ({ theme }: any) => string | any[];

export default styled.div`
  ${renderThemeProperty('backgroundColor', 'background-color')};
`
```

But in this case, I don't know which properties will come into my component. Should I parse that string?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for. However here is how I do if I need to set two different types of css. Just wrapped them using a `css` prop. Check [this](https://styled-components.com/docs/api) out

```
const themaA = css`
  //custom css
`
const themaB = css`
  //custom css
`

const YourStyledComponent = styled.div`
    ${props => (props.a ? themeA : themeB)};
`
```